# I tried to use next-auth in my nextJS App, but the error message says 'unable to verify the first certificate'

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I tried to use next-auth to login with google , but it ran into an error and it said 'unable to verify the first certificate'.[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is what my google authentication looks like:

```
pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
```

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

in the root directory, you should have
.env.local
where you should put
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=your_ID and
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=your_secret
For more info, please follow `https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google`